# Может ли сессия PHP сохранять данные переменной для повторного запуска той же страницы?

Tags: php, циклы, сессия, хранение-данных, передача-параметров

Хочу организовать повторный запуск цикла foreach с того момента, на котором он закончил при прошлом запуске программы.

Пришла в голову сессия.

Не могу понять, может ли она сохранять данные одного запуска программы и передавать ее в последующий запуск.. Вопрос, может, глупый, но во всех руководствах пишут о передаче сессионной информации на другую веб-страницу...

Вот для пробы запустил сессию:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php>
$x = 5 + 2;
$k = $x + 2;
$_SESSION["check"] = $x;
var_dump($k);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Если несколько раз запускать эту программу на одной и той же странице, то результат вычисления скрипта не меняется...

Я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас каждый раз задается значение $x, нужно наверное его все таки из сессии брать

```
if (isset($_SESSION["check"]))
{
    $x = $_SESSION["check"];
}
else {
    $x = 5 + 2;
}

$k = $x + 2;
$_SESSION["check"] = $k;
```